# How to make sure URL's are opened correctly in a progressive web app on android?

Tags: android, meteor, android-intent, progressive-web-apps

I have a meteor app running that can be *added to homescreen* on android. Doing this neatly installs the PWA. When I tap an URL in my system, the intent filter fires correctly and opens my app, but the thing is:

1. If my app is not open in the background, the intent fires correctly, opens my app and navigates to the correct URL.
2. If my app is open in the background the intent fires correctly and opens my app but doesn't navigate to the URL and the app just remains on the same page.

Any ideas as to how this is possible? Of course I want scenario 2 to also open the right URL directly.

I can't really control how the apk works on my phone because I believe chrome creates the apk when I use the "add to homescreen" function. I have setup the scope and start_url correctly in my webapps manifest.json. Perhaps I am missing a service worker I don't know about?

Comment: I assume you need to implement `onResume` to load the Intent data

Comment: @cricket_007 PWAs are all JavaScript and don't have access to the native Android methods like `onResume`.

Comment: @Arcnon in #2 does the PWA stay on the existing URL that was opened in the background? Or does the URL change to the one that was newly opened but the content isn't correctly updating?

Comment: This is long ago, but the PWA stayed on the existing URL. I don't seem to have the issue anymore though... Not sure if it was fixed with an update from Google.